# How can I use 'or' condition in variables block in AzureDevops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I'm trying to set the value of a var1 if mode is not dev or variable var2 has the value true

```
  - name: var1
    value: $[or(eq(variables['var2'], true), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))]
```

But when I run the pipeline, I see that the variable takes the value false

```
  var2:
    Parsing expression: <or(eq(variables['var2'], true), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))>
    Evaluating: or(eq(variables['var2'], True), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))
    Expanded: or(eq('$[or(eq(variables[''var2''], true), ne(variables[''Mode''], ''dev''))]', True), ne('dev', 'dev'))
    Result: 'False'
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you try alternate methods of variable expansion? Such as `variables.var2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this:

```yaml
variables:
- group: Some-secrets
- name: Mode
  value: prod
- name: var2
  value: true
- name: var1
  value: $[or(eq(variables['var2'], true), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))]


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: env | sort
  displayName: 'Display env variables'

- script: |
    echo "$(var1)"
    echo "$(var2)"
```

and it was evaluated properly:

```
  var1:
    Parsing expression: <or(eq(variables['var2'], true), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))>
    Evaluating: or(eq(variables['var2'], True), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))
    Expanded: or(eq('true', True), ne(variables['Mode'], 'dev'))
    Result: 'True'
```

Could you share you full pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to that you evaluate `var2` in `var2` same variable, should be var1, is it a typo?
[image]